# Amount of days to get Flameward Hippogryph and all Argent tournament mounts

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How many days of daily quests it'll take for you to actually complete all the requirements for the molten front offensive and gather enough champion seals to buy all mounts from the argent tournament?

Answer (score 6):

A lot.

**Molten Front** -- Up to about 29 days; see [this comment](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=416/mark-of-the-world-tree#comments:id=1472429) for a breakdown. Do note that the the comment is older, but I've found no indication that the number of Marks awarded have been increased since then.

It is apparently possible -- per [this guide](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=58/a-guide-to-the-molten-front-and-respective-quests) -- to realm hop and grab the alternate dailies that were *not* originally offered to you. Doing this would decrease your time to completion, though YMMV depending on what other quests you can find.

**Argent Tournament** -- There are 14 mounts available:

- Five available for 5 seals each plus gold
- Seven available for 100 seals each
- Two available for 150 seals each

That's 1025 seals needed for all mounts. You can obtain a max of 14/day with dailies, but it's also possible to solo (at max) Trial of the Champion (Heroic) for 3 more seals.

So, with only dailies, you'll need **74 days**; include Trial and you'll only need **61**. See [this comment](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=241/champions-seal#comments:id=1380285) for a breakdown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very clear and well explained! It'll take a lot of patience to farm it all.. Haha

Comment: I'd also recommend that, if you're into completionism, do Molten Front on a blacksmith, engineer, tailor, or leatherworker, so you can pick up the gated crafting recipes.

Comment: @ViniciusTerrabuio It's a lot of farming, but only a short time each day for doing the dailies, so it isn't too painful.